# Database First with POCOs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am new to **Entity Framework**, and I am trying to work with **POCOs**.  Most of the Tutorials seem to be **Database First** with **Generated Code** OR **Code First** with **POCOs**. There are not many *(though there are a few)* that deal with **Database First** with POCOs.

**My Setup:** 
I am trying to use EF in an existing project that is a bit large. To simply my question, I have attempted the following setup.

I have a project containing a single **EDMX Model**, connecting to a **single table** on a **Local DB**. Next, I copied the **Generated Code** from the ***Model.Designer.cs*** to another **.cs** file in the Project. I then set the **Code Generation Strategy** to ***None***. I then create a **Context Class** as below.

```
public class LocalDB : ObjectContext
{
    public const string ConnectionString = "name=LocalEntities";
    public const string ContainerName = "LocalEntities";

    public ObjectSet<Product_Listing> OpenList;

    public LocalDB() :  base(ConnectionString, ContainerName) 
    {
        OpenList = CreateObjectSet<Product_Listing>(); //InvalidOperationException!!
    }
}
```

**Problem:** 
When I hit the constructor, I get the following exception:

> **InvalidOperationException**.“Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'EFFTrial.LocalAccess.Product_Listing.”

I’d be grateful for any help. The book I have (by Lerman) is related to EF-4, but my code on VS 2010, and .Net 4 supports EF-6, I think. As I mentioned above, I am new, so I am not set on the versions as long as I can get by without .Net 4.5.

Comment: I'm a bit curious. Are you using `ObjectContext` and `ObjectSet` intentionally or just because you follow a book written for `EF4`?

Comment: **Leron** - As mentioned in the last para above, I am following Lerman's Programming EF book. Unfortunately, it is based on EF4, but I am not sure if it is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save yourself some trouble :

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

*EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator*

OR

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

*Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4*

*Reverse Engineer Code First - Generates POCO classes, derived DbContext and Code First mapping for an existing database.*

===========================================

Run it before you leave for the evening..and check your screen saver settings.  (Aka, it could take a while, esp the "Power Tools" one.

===========================================

Here is a Northwind "Customer" example.  Perhaps you can map it to your table.

```
namespace NorthWindyDataLayer.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {

        }

        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }

    }
}



using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
namespace NorthWindyDataLayer.Models
{
    public partial class WindyContext : DbContext
    {
        static WindyContext()
        {
            //Database.SetInitializer<WindyContext>(null);
        }

        public WindyContext()
            : base("Name=NorthwindContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomerMap());
        }
    }
}




using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace NorthWindyDataLayer.Models.Mapping
{
    public class CustomerMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
    {
        public CustomerMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.CustomerID);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.CustomerID)
                .IsRequired()
                .IsFixedLength()
                .HasMaxLength(5);

            this.Property(t => t.CompanyName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(40);

            this.Property(t => t.ContactName)
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            this.Property(t => t.ContactTitle)
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            this.Property(t => t.Address)
                .HasMaxLength(60);

            this.Property(t => t.City)
                .HasMaxLength(15);

            this.Property(t => t.Region)
                .HasMaxLength(15);

            this.Property(t => t.PostalCode)
                .HasMaxLength(10);

            this.Property(t => t.Country)
                .HasMaxLength(15);

            this.Property(t => t.Phone)
                .HasMaxLength(24);

            this.Property(t => t.Fax)
                .HasMaxLength(24);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("Customers");
            this.Property(t => t.CustomerID).HasColumnName("CustomerID");
            this.Property(t => t.CompanyName).HasColumnName("CompanyName");
            this.Property(t => t.ContactName).HasColumnName("ContactName");
            this.Property(t => t.ContactTitle).HasColumnName("ContactTitle");
            this.Property(t => t.Address).HasColumnName("Address");
            this.Property(t => t.City).HasColumnName("City");
            this.Property(t => t.Region).HasColumnName("Region");
            this.Property(t => t.PostalCode).HasColumnName("PostalCode");
            this.Property(t => t.Country).HasColumnName("Country");
            this.Property(t => t.Phone).HasColumnName("Phone");
            this.Property(t => t.Fax).HasColumnName("Fax");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used "Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 4" .. and I learned more about how EF does POCO mapping from that...than any book.  (If you already know your db schema fairly well).      OR        "Code up" your own Mini database DDL... with some basic 1:N , M:N , and M:N (with a relationship-attribute) tables...and reverse engineer that database.

Comment: Department.  Employee.  An Employee belongs to 1 Department and must have a Department.  Resource.  An Employee can have 0 or N Resource(s).   JobTitle.  An Employee can have 0 or N JobTitle(s) with a known StartDate.  (Note, the StartDate is an attribute of the relationship between Employee-JobTitle) ........   Write up that little database with all the tables, link tables and FK's...and you can reverse engineer how reverse POCO mapping works fairly quickly.

Comment: Thank you **granadaCoder**. I will look into these tools. However, I am curious what I am doing wrong. This is a simple table, and there are no foreign keys or any complications. Just int and Strings for Columns. I am trying to learn about the **Entity Framework** not just get my work done, so I would appreciate knowing what mistakes I am making.

Comment: I'm not saying do this because "its easy".  I'm saying.. you can learn much more quickly what the "set up is" when you reverse engineer something you know well.  You'll be like "oh, that's how that property gets mapped"........After I reverse engineered a simple database, I was able to "code up" myself another database.  I keep my Proof Of Concept around all the time.

Comment: Thank you **granadaCoder**. I know you have used the **Reverse POCO Generator** as you mentioned above, but I am curious if this is even **Entity Framework**. If you look at the **Connection String** in the `app.config` you would see that it uses the `SqlClient` instead of the `EntityClient`. Why? Is this the same as **Entity Framework**?

Comment: My ~total~ guess on that one is that the reverse Poco needs alot more data then provided by the EntityClient.  It has to read tables and FK and constraints...and that "language" can be differernt RDBMS to RDBMS.  If you've had to work with Oracle in any DBA or DDL mode, that would jump at you.  My ~~guess if that you could try to swap to Entity Client after the fact...since I think it is an abstracted-"up" version.  But I'm guessing......I'm not an expert here.